# How to Mock Token based authentication using spring security for unit testing spring boot rest controller?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to unit test the rest controller which is authenticate by JWT token using Spring security framework. I'm unable to find the way to mock the JWT token based authentication to test the rest controller.

Please let me know the process or share any link that'll be helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
     <version>6.2.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test

Using --> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc  you can call the api without the server.

In the call you can incorporate the jwt token by using --> org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt

example given below

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/your-endpoint")
            .with(jwt().jwt(builder -> builder.claim("username", "testUser"))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: builder.claim( ) showing error

Comment: will you share the code @SujayGhosh